# Manipulating data between two controllers in java

Tags: java, controllers

I have two controllers and want to manipulate data between them.

In my first controller I have the following inside initalize()

```
currCity = SettingsController.getCity();
currLat = SettingsController.getLat();
currLon = SettingsController.getLon();
```

In my SettingsController (second controller) I have the following

```
public String getCity() {
    return currCity;
}

public String getLat() {
    return currLat;
}

public String getLon() {
    return currLon;
}
```

How would I go about making something like this work? As right now I get non-static method cannot be referenced from static context.

Comment: Is for you ok/allowed to use callbacks??

Comment: Web environment? what tech you used?

Comment: This needs a *lot* more context. Generally speaking, you'd pass some sort of object (the model) between them.

Answer (score -1):

You can [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for the SettingsController.

But be careful with that pattern: 
[What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)